# SQL joins instead of nested query

Tags: sql

```
select baseurl from tmp_page_tbl 
where baseurl NOT IN ( select baseurl from page_lookup )
```

How do I write this query using joins instead of nesting it.

The idea is to get the baseurls from tmp tbl which do not exist in the page_lookup table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select baseurl
 from tmp_page_tbl t 
 left outer join page_lookup p on t.baseurl = p.baseurl 
 where p.baseurl IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite using joins like below:

```
SELECT baseurl from tmp_page_tbl as t
LEFT JOIN page_lookup as pl
ON t.baseurl=pl.baseurl
where pl.baseurl IS NULL
```

I'm not sure I would though unless you have a compelling reason.  Below are a few links worth looking at:

- http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/
- http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists/

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't selecting most of the table and you've index on page_lookup.baseUrl, then not exists should be most efficient.

```
select baseurl from tmp_page_tbl tmp
where not exists ( select 1 from page_lookup WHERE baseurl = tmp.baseurl );
```

On some RDBMS (Oracle DB and Postgres) you can use MINUS (or EXCEPT in Postgres). That is in some cases very efficient.

Comment: I agree with you but some people have reservations using nested queries vs joins i m just trying to figure out the best solution incase the lookup table grows very large